# Unexpected double redirect react Router v6

Tags: react-router

I am using react-router V6 for navigation and noticed strange behavior in navigation.
When you go to a new page, the following happens: go to the desired page, redirect back and again to the desired page.
This is not the first time I have used this version, but this is the first time I meet this behavior.
did anyone face a similar problem?

My routes.ts

```
const routes = (isLogged: boolean, dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('auth')) {
    <Navigate to="/login" />;
    revokeUserInfo(dispatch);
  }

  const revoke = () => {
    if (isLogged && isAuthExpired()) {
      revokeUserInfo(dispatch);
    }
    return false;
  };

  revoke();

  return [
    {
      path: 'app',
      element: isLogged ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to="/login" />,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          element: <Dashboard />
        },
        {
          path: 'chargers',
          element: <Outlet />,
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              element: <Chargers />
            },
            {
              path: ':id',
              element: <ChargerInfo />
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          path: 'location/:id',
          element: <LocationInfo />
        },
        {
          path: 'activity',
          element: <Outlet />,
          children: [
            {
              path: 'sessions',
              element: <Sessions />
            },
            {
              path: 'transactions',
              element: <Transactions />
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          path: 'business',
          element: <Outlet />,
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              element: <Business />
            },
            {
              path: ':id',
              element: <BusinessInfo />
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          path: '*',
          element: <Navigate to="/404" />
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: !isLogged ? <MainLayout /> : <Navigate to="/app/dashboard" />,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'login',
          element: <Login />
        },
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Navigate to="login" />
        },
        {
          path: 'resetPassword',
          element: <ResetPassword />
        },
        {
          path: '404',
          element: <NotFound />
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/404" />
    }
  ];
};

export default routes;
```

My App.tsx

```
const App: FC = () => {
  const { isLogged } = useSelector((state: RootStateType) => state.auth);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const routing = useRoutes(routes(isLogged, dispatch));

  return (
    <PersistGate
      loading={<Spinner />}
      persistor={persistor}
    >
      {/* Permissions Casl Context */}
      <AbilityContext.Provider value={ability}>
        {/* Material UI theme context Context */}
        <StylesProvider
          generateClassName={generateClassName}
          injectFirst
        >
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DayJsUtils}>
              {/* React-intl provider */}
              <AppIntlProvider>
                <CssBaseline />
                <GlobalStyles />
                {useScrollTop()}
                <ToastContainer />
                {routing}
              </AppIntlProvider>
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </StylesProvider>
      </AbilityContext.Provider>
    </PersistGate>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My DashboardLayout

```
const DashboardLayout: FC = () => {
  const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const classes = useStyles();

  const onMobileToggle = () => {
    setMobileNavOpen(!isMobileNavOpen);
  };

  const onMobileOpen = () => {
    setMobileNavOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <Box className={classes.root}>
      <DashboardSidebar
        onMobileToggle={onMobileToggle}
        openMobile={isMobileNavOpen}
        onMobileOpen={onMobileOpen}
      />
      <Box className={classes.wrapper}>
        <DashboardNavbar />
        <Box className={classes.container}>
          <Container
            maxWidth="xl"
            className={classes.content}
          >
            <Outlet />
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

Comment: It's likely that it's caused by your code. It's hard to troubleshoot blind so please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added parts of code. I hope it will help to understand my problem.